# Как загрузить картинку к посту в VK с помощью Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, python-3.x

Пытаюсь загрузить картинку вконтакте, прикрепить ее к посту и опубликовать все это на стену группы с помощью Python и VK Api.

Скрипт выглядит вот так:

```
session = vk.Session("Здесь_токен")
api = vk.API(session)

result = api.photos.getWallUploadServer(gid='110956219')
upload_url = result['upload_url']
img = {'photo': ('img.png', open(r'/home/sergiy/Изображения/img.png', 'rb'))}
response = requests.post(upload_url, files=img)
result = json.loads(response.text)
api.photos.saveWallPhoto(photo=json.loads(result['photo'])[0]['photo'], hash=result['hash'], server=result['server'], gid='110956219');
```

Но при попытке сохранить картинку, в последней строчке получаю ошибку: **vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 121. Invalid hash**

- ***Хэш*** передается верный;
- Права на публикацию в группе есть;
- Права у приложения **wall**, **photos**, **groups** есть;
- Параметр **gid** передается.

В чем еще может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) сказано:

> **Обратите внимание**, что ответ сервера всегда приходит в формате JSON, а поля **server, photo и hash** в нем содержат строки, внутренний формат которых может изменяться со временем. В частности, строка **photo** может содержать другой json-объект, который не следует декодировать, разбирать на части или иным образом модифицировать.

А вы этот самый photo и декодируете, и вытаскиваете из него часть:

```
api.photos.saveWallPhoto(photo=json.loads(result['photo'])[0]['photo'],...)
```

Как следствие, у этого photo получается совсем другой хэш, не совпадающий с переданным вами, на что ВК и ругается.

А надо просто не декодировать:

```
api.photos.saveWallPhoto(photo=result['photo'],...)
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно. Так работает, я пробовал такой подход без gid и соответственно не работало, потому я и отбросил его как устаревший.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
result = api.wall.getPhotoUploadServer(gid='110956219')
```

т.е. вместе `photos.getWall*` использовать `wall.getPhoto`.